# How to add language support (without installing extensions)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In order to enable vscode to recognize `.toml` and `.proto` files and display the corresponding icons, I followed the official documentation to do so:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.proto": "protocol buffer",
    "*.toml": "toml"
},
```

But vscode still cannot recognize `.toml` and `.proto` files.

Comment: Why don't you want to install extensions?

Comment: Because I found that if I install an extension like Toml extension, vscode will recognize the `.toml` file

Comment: Isn't that what you want?

Comment: What I want is that vscode correctly recognizes `.proto` and `.toml` files without installing any extensions, maybe my title is not clearly written

Comment: I'm not sure that makes any sense. You need an extension for it because VSCode has no built-in support and has no idea what "toml" or "protocol buffer" is supposed to be. If it did, you wouldn't need `files.assocations` in the first place.

Comment: Then I had to follow the extension of Toml and vscode-proto3 to do some extension locally